Using the DATA OPERATIONS Select to return an array of a JSON output from a compose
I have an API workflow that queries an on-premise DB. It returns a JSON of a few hundred records. These records are sent back to the requester. on success, I want to pull the rowguid value from the Response and then to send an array of rowguids to a stored procedure to update a flag on those records that were sent. I am trying to use the Data Operations Select. But I am stuck. I assume that the "From" is my output from the compose but what do I need in the Map (enter key and enter value)
This is one record of my output
    {
        "Location": "NewYork",
        "Salesorder": "15110000089420",
        "Vendor Name": "Holy",
        "rowguid": "D5890DEB-3E54-EF11-815E-0050568270D4"
    },


I took the sample input JSON and given to an array variable start_arr data like below.
[
{
        "Location": "NewYork",
        "Salesorder": "15110000089420",
        "Vendor Name": "Holy",
        "rowguid": "D5890DEB-3E54-EF11-815E-0050568270D4"
},
{
        "Location": "Dallas",
        "Salesorder": "15110000089421",
        "Vendor Name": "Kia",
        "rowguid": "AB890DEB-3E54-815E-EF11-0050568270D3"
},
{
        "Location": "DC",
        "Salesorder": "15110000089422",
        "Vendor Name": "Apple",
        "rowguid": "FTHIS81F-3E54-815E-EF11-0050568270D2"
},
{
        "Location": "Aus",
        "Salesorder": "15110000089423",
        "Vendor Name": "Hola",
        "rowguid": "ZB891DEB-3E54-815E-815E-0050568270D5"
}
]

To create the JSON array with required key, you need to give the key and value like below in the Map of the select data operation.
key - rowguid
value - item()?['rowguid'] - Go to the expression and give this expression and click on ok.


Then, you can store this array in an array variable like below.

Result:

